# How to properly type Python methods returning a dict with a generically typed instance and its generically typed property?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I have the following Python function and want to type it in a way that mypy understands
the return type as a dictionary, with the items' type as the value type and the id type as the key type:

```
def id_map(items):
    return {item.id: item for item in items}
```

The current approach looks like this:

```
from typing import Iterable, Protocol, TypeVar

S = TypeVar("S", covariant=True, bound="ClassWithId")
T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)

class ClassWithId(Protocol[S, T]):
    def __new__(cls: type[S], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> "ClassWithId[S, T]":
        ...

    @property
    def id(self: S) -> T:
        ...


def id_map(items: Iterable[ClassWithId[S, T]]) -> dict[T, S]:
    return {item.id: cast(S, item) for item in items}
```

This currently results in the type `builtins.dict[Any, Any]`. I cannot think of a different implementation that would make that work.
I am wondering whether this is possible at all using mypy.

Comment: why is `__new__` part of your protcol?

Comment: I tried using `__new__` to enforce the typing inference. However that didn't work out.

Comment: ``S`` seems to be the self variable. Do *not* include it as a generic of the class, just let it be inferred.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that was also an attempt to enforce the inference of the `S` type var. If I take this and the `__new__` out, how would mypy infer `S`  to be an instance of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Remove the self type variable `S`. It is not needed but leads to a type relation that is unlikely to be understood by type checkers.

```
class ClassWithId(Protocol[T]):
    @property
    def id(self) -> T:
        ...
```

---

Type variables can be used in two flavours: as *inferred* variables in a call or as *declared* variables in a generic type. Use the former for types that are constrained from usage context, and the latter for types that must be consistent across an entire class.

The `S` type var is a `Self` type; this can always be inferred from usage and does not need to be repeated in the type itself. Otherwise, you construct a recursive type which is likely to confuse current type checkers.

Removing `S` from the generic/protocol shows that it is not actually used for any type relation: The `T` is fully constrained by the class `ClassWithId[T]`. There is no need to refer to `S` to define any relation between input and output.

```
class ClassWithId(Protocol[T]):
    @property
    def id(self: S) -> T: ...
    #                  ^ defined by generic class, not S
```

Notice how `id_map` also does not depend on `S` – knowing either of `T` or `ClassWithId[T]` is enough to know the other. As a result, one can remove `S` completely.

```
T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)

class ClassWithId(Protocol[T]):
    @property
    def id(self) -> T:
        ...

def id_map(items: Iterable[ClassWithId[T]]) -> dict[T, ClassWithId[T]]:
    return {item.id: item for item in items}
```

---

If `id_map` is supposed to preserve the *exact* `ClassWithId[T]` and not just the protocol, this corresponds to a *higher kinded type*. In principle, this is expressed by a Type variable with a bound of the protocol.

```
CWI = TypeVar("CWI", bound=ClassWithId)

def id_map(items: Iterable[CWI[T]]) -> dict[T, CWI[T]]:
    return {item.id: item for item in items}
```

However, [MyPy does not supported higher kinded types at the moment](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548).

Comment: I had this version. However this does not properly keep the type of the objects put into the method but returns only a more generic `ClassWithId[T]`.

Comment: @naechtner Are you looking for a higher kinked type, i.e. ``def id_map(items: Iterable[S[T]]) -> dict[T, S[T]]:``? This would still not need ``S`` in the protocol, only in ``id_map``. I'm afraid that MyPy does not understand such types, though.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not detailed enough. But the higher kinded type is exactly what I wanted. I was afraid though, that this would not be possible.

Comment: @naechtner I've added a part on the higher kinded types, but I'm afraid the gist is "doesn't work" for the time being. :/